# uname on Windows Terminal

Tags: windows, terminal

I was wondering if the command `uname` works in Windows terminal? If so what does it output? I read that it could be `Windows` or `WindowsNT`

Comment: Unless you install MinGW/MSYS, there's no uname command in Windows. Even with WSL all you'll get is Linux

Comment: @Martheen Is there an equivalent command to `uname` in windows?

Comment: ver perhaps? But it doesn't just show the OS name

Answer (score 2):

I believe uname shows you your kernel. So on GNU/Linux, running uname gives you Linux because that is your kernel. Out of Windows or WindowsNT, I'd assume Windows would give you Windows NT because that's the kernel it uses.

```
$ whatis uname
uname (1)            - print system information
uname (2)            - get name and information about current kernel
```

I think you can get similar information by using `systeminfo`.

Answer (score 2):

in Windows, uname-equivalent is the 'ver' command.

```
>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1889]
```

you can create a tiny script, call it uname.cmd

```
>type uname.cmd
@ver
```

Then you have your own uname command on Windows

```
>uname

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1889]
```

I tested the above on my Windows 10 PC.